# How access a variable which is declared in one object from another object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access the variable which is declared in one object from another object here its not working
My **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/txvzq/1/)**
**My script:**

```
$(function(){
homePage.tooltipshowhide();
homePage.hidetooltip();
});

(function( $ ){ 

    homePage = {

    tooltipshowhide:function(){
        var time = 0;
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip({html:true,placement: 'bottom',trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
        time = setInterval(homePage.hidetooltip, 4000);
    },

    hidetooltip:function(){
        clearInterval(time);
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip('destroy');
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip({html:true});
        $('#continueBtnTop').removeClass('toggle-ttp');
    }

 };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: I am getting this error ----> Uncaught ReferenceError: homePage is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by defining the variable outside the function and changing its scope:

```
(function( $ ){ 

homePage = {
    toimeone: 0,
    tooltipshowhide:function(){
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip({html:true,placement: 'bottom',trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
        this.toimeone = setInterval(homePage.hidetooltip, 4000);
    },

    hidetooltip:function(){
        clearInterval(this.toimeone);
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip('destroy');
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip({html:true});
        $('#continueBtnTop').removeClass('toggle-ttp');
    }

};
})( jQuery );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txvzq/2/

Comment: I am getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: homePage is not defined

Comment: There are other issues with your code, I've fixed a few of them: http://jsfiddle.net/txvzq/8/

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to define time variable out of object and other is to define this variable as object field like this

```
$(function(){
    homePage.tooltipshowhide();
    homePage.hidetooltip();
});
(function( $ ){ 
    homePage = {
    time: 0,

    tooltipshowhide:function(){
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip(
            {html:true,placement: 'bottom',trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
        this.time = setInterval(homePage.hidetooltip, 4000);
    },

    hidetooltip:function(){
        clearInterval(this.time);
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip('destroy');
        $('.toggle-ttp').tooltip({html:true});
        $('#continueBtnTop').removeClass('toggle-ttp');
    }

 };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Two differents scopes...

You should be do something like this (create the object and only after invoke these object methods:

```
;(function( $ ){ 
 window.homePage = {}
 // ...
});

;(function($) {
 window.homePage = window.homePage || {};
 window.homePage.tooltipshowhide();
 // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable outside of the homePage object.